# Detect an image's dimensions as early as possible

Tags: javascript, image

I know the browser can detect image sizes early on, by how it reserves the space early in the download and then fills in the area with the image as it loads.

My question is, is there any way I can get a hold of that? Is there some event that fires when the browser has information on the image such as its size?

Comment: A bit of context on what you're trying to do would be nice. It seems like an XY problem at first glance...

Comment: I'm making a lightbox-like popup to view a fullsize image. It's rather more bare-bones and "functional over beautiful" than the real thing, but it works in a similar way. It loads the image and then positions it so that it is centred on-screen, or stops at the top-left and becomes scrollable as needed. If I can get the dimensions early, then the larger images become scrollable sooner.

Comment: Can the browser really figure out the dimensions before fully loading the image? I always thought it only reserved the space when the img tag includes width/height attributes.

Comment: Yes. All the main image formats include the canvas size as one of their header fields.

Comment: I was thinking the same thing as @bfavaretto, but if it can figure out the dimensions without any sort of attribute or CSS definition, and as a result it pre-sized the area, then it would seem there's no issue. You should just be able to get the dimensions from the element, or its parent if the parent wraps to the size of the image.

Comment: ...or at worst, you could do a little polling to grab that info as soon as it's available (or close to it).

Comment: @Kolink Do you know what response header indicates the image size? http://www.w3.org/Protocols/rfc2616/rfc2616-sec14.html

Comment: @HMR, He's not talking about response headers, but data headers embedded in the image file itself.

Comment: Oh, I see. That would make unload trigger after the browser knows the image size. +1, excelent question. In gimp; when I export to png I can check or uncheck "save resolution" this would suggest that this meta data is optional.

Comment: I think you're stuck with an onload handler.  I don't think I've actually written one of those since jQuery though--no help from me with cross-browser support I'm afraid :P

Answer (score 0):

I've used an onLoad event attached to the image itself in the past. It often fires before the image has been drawn by the browser, but that may not be early enough for your purposes.